# Configuring RabbitMQ management docker image with default setup & access UI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

### Background

I need to setup a `docker-compose` with a RabbitMQ service and my application. This RabbitMQ service needs to have 3 things to work properly:

- a user named "user1" with full permissions
- a vhost named "vhost1"
- inside "vhost1", I need an exchange called "Pizza"

### What we tried

To achieve this we tried creating a folder in our project called  `rabbitmq` with the following files:

**definitions.json**

```
{
    "rabbit_version": "3.6.6",
    "users": [
     {
      "name": "user1",
      "password_hash": "pass1",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": "administrator"
     }
    ],
    "vhosts": [
     {
      "name": "\/vhost1"
     }
    ],
    "permissions": [
     {
      "user": "user1",
      "vhost": "\/vhost1",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
     }
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [],
    "queues": [],
    "exchanges": [],
    "bindings": []
   }
```

**rabbitmq.conf**

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
```

We are mounting this folder using the `volumes` command from `docker-compose` using the following file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - "8080:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes: 
      - ${PWD}/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq
```

### Problems

We are facing two issues at the moment:

1. we are **not** creating the exchange called "Pizza".
2. we cannot access the RabbitMQ management UI via `localhost:8080` even though we specify the mapping of this port in our `docker-compose` file.

### Questions

1. How do we define an exchange for a vhost in the `defininitions.json` file? (where can I read about it?)
2. Why can't we access the UI? What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solutions

### 1. Exchange creation

The first issue is easily solvable. The reason the exchange is not being created is because the `"exchanges"` field in the the `definitions.json` file is empty. To fix this you need to add an exchange object to that list:

```
"exchanges": [
    {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "vhost": "\/vhost1",
      "type": "fanout",
      "durable": true,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "internal": false,
      "arguments": {}
    }
  ],
```

One can read more about this in this blog post:

https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/creating-a-custom-rabbitmq-container-with-preconfigured-queues.html

### 2. Accessing the management UI

Here there are several problems with the configurations. First, I was smashing the contents of the original `/etc/rabbitmq` folder in the container with the ones in my local folder. This was not intended, and the fix to this issue can be found here:

[Unknown variable "management.load_definitions" in rabbitmq rabbit.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193789/unknown-variable-management-load-definitions-in-rabbitmq-rabbit-conf-file/59197626#59197626)

The second issue was in the `rabbitmq.conf` file. We were missing the field that tells the application to load our definitions file. Following is the correct version of the `rabbitmq.conf` file:

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

The third (and final) issue was with the user's password, specifically the `password_hash` field, which needs to follow a specific algorithm and be encoded in a specific format. More about this can be read in RabbitMQ's official documentation:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/passwords.html

To skip the pain of dealing with the salting, hashing and encoding, if all you want is to test a setup for integration purpose like we want, then just go with the password `test12` that is given in the example:

```
"users": [
     {
      "name": "user1",
      "password_hash": "kI3GCqW5JLMJa4iX1lo7X4D6XbYqlLgxIs30+P6tENUV2POR",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": "administrator"
     }
    ]
```

If however, it is really important for you to know how to generate user passwords that RabbitMQ will accept here is a bash script, created by the blood and tears of a colleague:

```
#!/bin/bash
PWD_HEX=$(echo -n $1 | xxd -p)
SALT="908D C60A" 
HEX="$SALT $PWD_HEX"
SHA256=$(echo -n $HEX | xxd -r -p | sha256sum)
# This is thw pwd to be inserted on your rabbit load_definitions file
echo "908D C60A $SHA256" | xxd -r -p | base64
```

Usage: `./my_script userpass1`

### Conclusion

And with all this out of the way one should be able to create users, vhosts and exchanges while also having access to the management UI, all via a docker image.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is PHP 7.3+ version o pass generator: `php -r '$pass = "test12"; $salt = random_bytes(4); var_dump(base64_encode($salt . hash("sha256", $salt.$pass, true)));'` You can test it by changing `$salt="\x90\x8D\xC6\x0A"` should output `kI3GCqW5JLMJa4iX1lo7X4D6XbYqlLgxIs30+P6tENUV2POR`