# Unknown variable "management.load_definitions" in rabbitmq rabbit.conf file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

### Background

We have a RabbitMQ management docker image in a `docker-compose` setup and we are trying to launch rabbit with some users, vhosts and exchanges already added. However, the bootup is crashing and we don't know why.

### What we tried

We have a folder called "rabbitmq" with the following files (this is our configuration folder):

**definitions.json**

```
{
    "rabbit_version": "3.8.2",
    "users": [
     {
      "name": "user1",
      "password_hash": "user1",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": ""
     }
    ],
    "vhosts": [
     {
      "name": "\/vhost1"
     }
    ],
    "permissions": [
     {
      "user": "user1",
      "vhost": "\/vhost1",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
     }
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [],
    "queues": [],
    "exchanges": [
        {
            "name": "Pizza",
            "vhost": "\/vhost1",
            "type": "fanout"
        }
    ],
    "bindings": []
   }
```

**rabbitmq.conf**

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.load_definitions = "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"
```

To make use of this setup, we have the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.2-management
    ports:
      - "8080:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes: 
      - ${PWD}/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq
```

We know that RabbitMQ finds this folder and tries to load the `rabbitmq.conf` file. In fact, this is where our issues start.

### Problem

When we try to launch our setup, RabbitMQ fails to launch with the following message:

```
BOOT FAILED
rabbit_1  | ===========
rabbit_1  |
rabbit_1  | Config file generation failed:
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.479 [error] You've tried to set management.load_definitions, but there is no setting with that name.
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.479 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.537 [error]     load_definitions
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.537 [error]     raft.segment_max_entries
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.537 [error]     log.syslog.identity
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.537 [error] Error generating configuration in phase transform_datatypes
rabbit_1  | 10:46:43.537 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: management.load_definitions
rabbit_1  | In case the setting comes from a plugin, make sure that the plugin is enabled.
rabbit_1  | Alternatively remove the setting from the config.
rabbit_1  |
rabbit_1  | init terminating in do_boot (generate_config_file)
rabbit_1  | {"init terminating in do_boot",generate_config_file}
rabbit_1  |
rabbit_1  | Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
```

This is confusing. We are using the `rabbitmq:3.8.2-management` image, so the management plugin should be enabled by default.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: It may be worth pointing out as well that the rabbitmq.conf is incorrect and that the double quotes (") should be removed from the filename and be 
`management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json`
This took me a bit to understand why couldn't find the json file and removing the quotes finally worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

The reason why we were getting this error was in the `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.2-management
    ports:
      - "8080:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes: 
      - ${PWD}/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq
```

Specifically the volumes part: `${PWD}/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq`

The issue here is that this command completely smashes the original rabbitmq folder with ours. This means that all the extra files in the original /etc/rabbitmq fodler are lost.

This was not our purpose, our purpose was to add our files to the original folder, replacing said files if they already existed.

### The solution

The following `docker-compose` fixes this issue:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.2-management
    ports:
      - "8080:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes: 
      - ${PWD}/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
      - ${PWD}/rabbitmq/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

Here we only push and replace the files we need, letting the rest of the content from the original folder untouched.

This means that the plugins folder inside `/etc/rabbitmq` won't be deleted and that the plugins (such as the management one) will be loaded and we will be able to configure them via the `rabbitmq.conf` file.